# Process microphone data in real time in java

Tags: java, real-time, signal-processing, microphone

I'm using this instructions for get a signal audio of a microphone:

```
while(!stopCapture){

            int cnt = targetDataLine.read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.length);
            if(cnt > 0){
              byteArrayOutputStream.write(tempBuffer, 0, cnt);            
            }
          }
          byteArrayOutputStream.close();
          byte audio[] = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
          InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(audio);
          AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(input, audioFormat, audio.length / audioFormat.getFrameSize());
```

But these instructions wait the entire signal before elaborate it.
I need elaborate it in real time...is possible?

How can i do it?

thanks

Comment: Do the 'elaborating' (whatever that means) in the line before `byteArrayOutputStream.write(tempBuffer, 0, cnt);`.

Comment: i need to get the amplitutes of the signal. can i get them by tempbuffer directly?

Comment: What do you mean by 'amplitude'?  The instantaneous size of the a sound wave can be obtained from the bytes of the frames, but that is not the same thing as the volume of the sound.  Volume calculations require a group of frames.

Comment: Getting amplitude(s) depends on the length of the buffer of samples and the frequency response you desire for the amplitude measurement.